# Piping two command from makefile is not working

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

I use the following commands in my `makefile`

```
apps := $(shell fzr provide apps )
apps := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(apps)))
```

in the commands im getting array of values
and remove the array `[]` from it,

I want to run this command in my terminal and I use the following

`fzr provide apps | (subst ],,$(subst [,,$(apps))) | $(apps)`

and I got error

```
bash: apps: command not found
bash: apps: command not found
bash: subst: command not found
bash: subst: command not found
```

what am I missing here ?

if I run only

`fzr provide apps`

I got, which works

`[app1 app2 app3]`

**The idea is to inspect command**

`apps := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(apps)))`

which works on mac but in **windows it's** not ...

Comment: Are you trying to run this command on Windows? How did you setup `bash` there? Windows has its own command-line language (two of them, actually), but `bash` is not one of them by default.

Comment: @JennyM : The error message means, that you want to execute a command named `apps`, and there is no executable file of this name in any directory listed in your PATH, nor is it a function or an alias. As a first step, I would investigate the value of PATH at the time the command is executed and verify whether this file is present and has the x-bit set.

Comment: @JennyM : Aside from this, even if their were a command of this name in PATH, the expression `$(apps)` is a bit unusual: It mean _invoke the command **apps**, and treat the stdout of this command as the name of a new command, which is invoked next and receives the input of the pipe_ ... Are you sure that this is what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands which are valid in a Makefile are not valid on the terminal prompt.

If you want to remove the leading and trailing square brackets in a Bash script, try

```
fzr provide apps |
sed 's/^\[//;s/\]$//'
```

If you want to put that in a `Makefile`, note that you will need to double the dollar sign (a single dollar sign gets evaluated by `make` itself; doubling it passes through a literal dollar sign to the shell).

```
apps := $(shell fzr provide apps | sed 's/^\[//;s/\]$$//')
```

Your `Makefile` uses syntax which is specific to GNU Make; perhaps the `make` version you have on Windows is not a GNU-compatible one.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it and let you know :) , by the way I download for windows from here , http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm ,is it compatible?

Comment: I have no way to test it but the cover page says it's GNU Make.

Comment: if I want to use this in makefile, `fzr provide apps |
sed 's/^\[//;s/\]$//'` this should work ?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover that around a minute ago (^:

Comment: Thank you , when I try it in my makefile I get `unknown command sed` :(

Comment: The `Makefile` obviously cannot use any commands which are not installed on your Windows box. It's not hard to find a Windows `sed` though it may be simpler to revert to the `$(subst ...)` if you want to avoid pulling in a lot of dependencies. There is no sane way to make a nontrivial `Makefile` portable between Windows and real computers, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter version of the script that @tripleee posted:

```
fzr provide apps | tr -d '[]'
```

This removes `[` or `]` characters wherever they appear in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

In your makefile, `$(apps)` expands to the value of the makefile variable `apps`.   This is done at makefile read time, and the value is substituted before the shell command is executed (thus the shell never sees `$(apps)`, but rather sees `appval1`, or whatever apps happens to be.

In the shell, (I'm assuming a bash shell), `$(apps)` means run command `apps`.    If you want the value of the shell variable you have to use `${apps}`.   In addition, `$(subst)` is a make construct, and the shell does not understand that either, so you have to replace that with something (likely `sed`).

So, in this case you would need to do something like:

```
fzr provide apps | sed "s/[][]//g"
```

Note: this replaces all square brackets, not just leading and trailing.  If you want to just do the leading and trailing ones, see tripleee's answer.